# Inserting json file into Cassandra table

Tags: json, ruby, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-ruby-driver

I am currently using the Cassandra-Ruby driver to insert data from a JSON file into an existing table in my database.

the JSON file looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "123",
    "destination": "234",
    "type": "equipment",
    "support": "type 1",
    "test": "test1"
  },
  {
    "id": "234",
    "destination": "123",
    "type": "equipment",
    "support": "type 1",
    "test": "test1"
  }
]
```

I am reading in the file like this:

```
file = File.read('itemType.json')
data_hash = JSON.parse(file) #return an array of hashes
```

Iterate through the array and get each hash
and insert each hash onto the table

```
data_hash.each do |has|
  #check the type of each object
  #puts has.class #return hash
  insert_statement = session.prepare('INSERT INTO keyspace.table JSON ?')
  session.execute(insert_statement, [has])  #error occurs here
end
```

After running this code, I get this error message

```
in `assert_instance_of': options must be a Hash
```

I checked that each object being inserted in the table is a hash, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are saying that you are inserting a `JSON` but you are not, you are trying to insert an object. See this example from the documentation:

```
 INSERT INTO cycling.cyclist_category JSON '{
  "category" : "Sprint", 
  "points" : 700, 
  "id" : "829aa84a-4bba-411f-a4fb-38167a987cda"
}';
```

You have to give it a json format if you do it like that.

Comment: even if I convert each object into JSON using `.to_json` method, I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Are `keyspace.table` the correct key space name and table name?

Comment: yes, everything is correct since I can query from them.

Comment: could you provide the string result of has.to_json?

Comment: @ArthurLandim, it's the same string format of the JSON from the file.

Answer (score 1):

using `.to_json` add `\` escape character. This gave me error

```
INSERT INTO organization_metadata JSON '{\"id\":9150,\"destroyed\":false,\"name\":\"ABC\",\"timestamp\":1510541801000000000}';
```

and the following worked.

```
INSERT INTO organization_metadata JSON '{"id":9150,"destroyed":false,"name":"ABC","timestamp":1510541801000000000}';
```